# run gnome-mag on kali linux

Tags: gnome, kali-linux

when i want to run gnome magnifier with command `gnome-mag` it says `command not found`!!
but when i want to install it by `apt-get install gnome-mag` it says that "it is already installed"!!

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-mag is already the newest version.
gnome-mag set to manually installed.
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the executable isn't `gnome-mag`, it's `magnifier`.

#### Consulting packages

It's a good habit to always consult a package's contents to see what's installed when you run into issues like this.

*Searching through apt*

You can use `apt-file` to search for a filename via apt.

```
$ apt-file search gnome-mag
gdm: /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/gnome-mag.desktop
gnome-mag: /usr/share/doc/gnome-mag/AUTHORS
gnome-mag: /usr/share/doc/gnome-mag/NEWS.gz
gnome-mag: /usr/share/doc/gnome-mag/README
gnome-mag: /usr/share/doc/gnome-mag/changelog.Debian.gz
gnome-mag: /usr/share/doc/gnome-mag/copyright
gnome-mag: /usr/share/gnome-mag/1_32/appstart.xpm
...
```

*Search through already installed packages*

You can use `dpkg` to search for a filename within all the packages already installed.

```
$ dpkg -L gnome-mag
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/magnifier
/usr/share
/usr/share/gnome-mag
...
```